# Serial Communication read() Error

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

This should be fairly straightforward for someone in the know, but I have been struggling for a bit and would appreciate some thoughts.  I am writing an application that reads from a serial comm port.

My Setup:

I have a windows machine with putty open and connected to my comm port of interest.
I have a linux (ubuntu) machine in which I am writing this software (in C).
I am typing into putty on the windows machine and trying to read it with my application on the linux machine.

What I have:

So far, using the code below I can successfully write to the putty display on the windows machine from my application on the linux computer, but I cannot read the buffer on my linux machine when I type on the windows machine.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>      // standard input / output functions
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>     // string function definitions
#include <unistd.h>     // UNIX standard function definitions
#include <fcntl.h>      // File control definitions
#include <errno.h>      // Error number definitions
#include <termios.h>

int openport()
{
    int USB = open( "/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR| O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK );
    struct termios tty;
    struct termios tty_old;
    memset(&tty, 0, sizeof tty);

    /* Error Handling */
    if ( tcgetattr( USB, &tty ) != 0 )
    {
        printf("Error 1, or something");
    }

    /* Save old tty parameters */
    tty_old = tty;

    /* Set Baud Rate */
    cfsetospeed (&tty, (speed_t)B9600);
    cfsetispeed (&tty, (speed_t)B9600);

    /* Setting other Port Stuff */
    tty.c_cflag     &=  ~PARENB;        // Make 8n1
    tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSTOPB;
    tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSIZE;
    tty.c_cflag     |=  CS8;

    tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CRTSCTS;       // no flow control
    tty.c_cc[VMIN]      =   1;                  // read doesn't block
    tty.c_cc[VTIME]     =   5;                  // 0.5 seconds read timeout
    tty.c_cflag     |=  CREAD | CLOCAL;     // turn on READ & ignore ctrl lines

    /* Make raw */
    cfmakeraw(&tty);
    /* Flush Port, then applies attributes */
    tcflush( USB, TCIFLUSH );
    if ( tcsetattr ( USB, TCSANOW, &tty ) != 0)
    {
        printf("Error, or something");
    }

    return USB;
}

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    int j = 0;
    unsigned char buf[10] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    printf("Hello world!\n");

    int USB = openport();


    unsigned char cmd[] = "INIT Hey SHanahas \r";
    int n_written = 0;

    do 
    {
        n_written += write( USB, &cmd[n_written], 1 );
    }
    while (cmd[n_written-1] != '\r' && n_written > 0);

    printf("Here\n\n");


    do
    {
        n = read( USB, &buf, 1 );
        printf("%s \n",buf);
        printf("%d",n);
    }
    while( buf != '\r' && n > 0);



    printf("Herr2");

    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on what might be happening?  the read() command returns a -1 error.

Thanks!

Comment: You probably forgot some Linux or Posix tag. Your question is definitely operating-system specific! On Linux, when `read` fails by returning -1, you should consider `errno` (e.g. display it using `perror`)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, the error it gives is a "Resource temporarily unavailable"  Will look into that

Comment: You should read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and consider using some multiplexing syscall like [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)

Comment: As already pointed out by *Basile*, especially for `read()`, error checking and logging is essential for successful debugging. You should do this for all (system) calls.